# dataform webpart button redirect new ID after saving

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, xslt-list-view-web-part, data-form-web-part, redirect

I have two DataFormWebparts on a page, one for creating new objects, one to edit them.
The Webpart that creates them has this button :

```
<input type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave0" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__refresh;__redirect={Page.aspx?SelectedID_x003D__x007B_@ID_x007D_}')}" />
```

The actions for the button I have set from Sharepoint Designer 2010, as follows:

- Commit
- Refresh
- Navigate to page (same page but with parameter SelectedID set with value:
  ',/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@ID,'

The logic that should happen is: save the object, then redirect to the same page but with the ID of the newly created object in the XsltListviewWebPart.

What actually happens, the redirect works but to:

```
https://domain.com/SitePages/Page.aspx?SelectedID=%27,/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@ID,%27
```

I see two problems, first -the redirected URL seems to be encoded. Second, the parameter is simply taken as string, not considered as an actual parameter.

Can anyone please give a hint on what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing this:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave0" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__refresh;__redirect={Page.aspx?SelectedID_x003D__x007B_@ID_x007D_}')}" />
```

with

```
<input type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave0" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__refresh;__redirect={Page.aspx?SelectedID={@ID}}')}" />
```

if that doesn't works, you can use substring(@ID,[start-index],[length]) or substring-after or substring-before in xslt